# Is there a way to match — or clean up — a forked git local repository branches to what exists upstream?

Tags: git, source-control, revision-control

I have a fork of [ERPNext](https://github.com/frappe/erpnext) from several months ago. Upstream has cleaned out a lot of branches since I forked, so my repo now has 184 branches, while upstream only has 41 branches.

Is there a way to sync the removal of those branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, go into the repo on the command line and type in this command:

```
git remote prune origin
```

That will clean out non-existent branches on the remote. If you are nervous about running that command just add `--dry-run` to that command to see what branches would be removed like this:

```
git remote prune origin --dry-run
```

Just note that if you checked out any of those 184 locally on your machine, the command won’t affect those. The `prune` command cleans out remote references. So if you don’t need any of those checked out branches locally you need to run the standard delete command:

```
git branch -D [name of branch]
```